# Excel - Tell if Column A a third of Column B

Tags: excel-formula

I'm drawing a blank how to do what I think is a simple formula with a color change.

```
I have two columns see below  
A | B
------
3 | 9
25| 10
```

I want to change the value in Column A is a third of Column B so the first row the 3 should be highlighted in red where as the second row just be left alone. I have tried MOD, IF statements to keep it simple but just tripping over myself.
Any pointers to functions or a start of a formula at a high level like IF(column b / column a) will lead me to my answer be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: formula rule `=A1=B1/3`

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance as obviously made it more complicated in my head trying to figure a solution. Have a great day